# Looking to create burner accounts

Tags: mail-server

I have about 150 students next semester and I would like to provide each student with their own burner email address so that I can require them to subscribe to various websites. At the end of the semester, I'll delete all the accounts.

I found https://thehelm.com, but I'm looking for a free way to create burner email accounts.

I have a domain hosted on a VPS, but using smartermail would cost additional.

Comment: I think I'll use gmx.

Comment: Why not advise them to do by them self? like who doesn't have a spam address? If they still want it then, they can also keep it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your VPS to host an unlimited number of emails.

1. Register a domain name for your VPS.
2. Setup the appropriate `MX` records that point to your server.
3. Open port 25 to allow SMTP traffic and port 80 for web traffic.
4. Install an SMTP server: Postfix, Sendmail... See [Comparison_of_mail_servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers)
5. Install a web server and a webmail client to provide a web interface for mail. I like [squirrelmail](https://squirrelmail.org/). You could use pop3d or imapd if you prefer a local client.

The only limit to using this method is the storage limit on the VPS.

This is not free(5-30 dollars a year for the domain name + VPS costs), but you can host as many emails on it as space allows. As an educators bonus, you have the ability to monitor all email activity, as permitted within your acceptable use policy.

Answer (score 1):

Do they need the emails themselves? Or do they just need to create an account? I'm just thinking that gmail has a functionality where you can postfix an email address with +(something) and sites will think it's a distinct email address, but gmail servers will acknowledge it as the same email.

For example if my email address were danny@gmail.com I could have the following email addresses:

```
danny+1@gmail.com
danny+2@gmail.com
danny+steve@gmail.com
etc.
```

These look like distinct emails for the purpose of creating accounts on websites, but all the emails from those 150 different accounts will end up in the same inbox. You can just share the login credentials for the 1 email address with all 150 students (or you could create 1 gmail per class of 30, 5 in total).

Comment: The emails themselves.